# Get identifier from recently added Event (EKEventStore saveEvent)

Tags: iphone, eventkit

I am saving a custom Event with EKEventStore saveEvent to the calendar the return value is boolean so I can handle if the storage process fails. Is there any chance to easily find out the unique identifier for this event, so I can fetch it afterwards with eventWithIdentifier? I don't want to make a selection by date cause it could return more then one result. Is there any other posibility to fetch "my" event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(NSString *) uniqueIdentifier = myEvent.eventIdentifier;
```

That's it.